# Appropriate use of the term "transversely"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

In the following paragraph, is it appropriate to use the term "*transversely*" to describe something that has the opposite effect?

> Tests have shown that the lower the range, the more likely that a submatrix will
>   be singular.  Transversely, the larger the range, the least likely that a submatrix
>   will be singular.

If not, is there another word that I can use instead?  I know that, in this instance, I cannot use the word "conversely" as this means something totally different.

Comment: I'm not sure... why doesn't "conversely" work here?

Comment: Hi @simchona, (I believe) the reason why "conversely" won't work here is because in mathematical speak, the converse of a statement A implies B, is B implies A.  In the example that I have provided above, I have more or less negated the statement.  I could, however, be wrong.

Comment: "Conversely" is, indeed, better.  The converse "B implies A" may equivalently be given as "not A implies not B".  (On another note, "least" should be "less".)

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar, I wasn't certain whether "conversely" was appropriate in this case.  You more or less confirmed it in my mind.

Comment: Correction: @GEdgar - no disrespect but, the explanation you give as to the meaning of "converse" is actually the "contrapositive".  I only just realised that when I read your reply again.  I think I may stick to "In contrast..." or "On the other hand..." as suggested below.

Comment: @GEdgar (and Bill) Given an original statement of "A implies B", "B implies A" is the converse of this statement, "not A implies not B" is the inverse, and "not B implies not A" is the contrapositive.  The inverse is the contrapositive of the converse, and though an implication and its contrapositive have the same truth value (in binary logic, at least), the actual presentation of the statement is what distinguishes the converse from the inverse.

Comment: I would consider what the speaker was trying to mean, using the word 'transversely'. Perhaps they are trying to say 'along a line of reasoning different from this one'.

Comment: @GEdgar (and others) - I take back what I said about your argument being the contrapositive.  It is the inverse which, in fact, is the correct answer.  Sorry about that - it's been a long day.... :-(

Comment: I'm puzzled about the contrasting ranges being 'lower' and 'larger'.  A 'low range' might be appropriate for music or gears, and the opposite would be a 'high range'.  A 'large range' might be appropriate for where a species is found in the wild or the difference between the smallest and largest values in a matrix, and the opposite would be a 'small range'.

Comment: @Johathan Leffler - Actually, I have taken the paragraph out of its context.  The sentence prior to this paragraph referred to a random selection of values between -n and n, hence the 'range' of values.  Maybe I should have used 'smaller' or 'larger' range, instead.

Answer (score 9):

No, transversely is incorrect. You might consider "In contrast ..." or "On the other hand...".

Comment: Thanks for that @Fraser Orr.  I think I will stick to "In contrast..." just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 4):

I would use "inversely", as in "inversely proportional".

Comment: Thanks for that @Hack Saw.  Although I do believe your suggestion of using the term "inversely" more accurately reflects what I want to describe, I think I will stick to "In contrast..." just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 4):

If we have a statement:

> The lower the range, the more likely that a submatrix will be singular.

the logical *converse* of the statement is:

> The more likely that a submatrix will be singular, the lower the range.

and the logical *inverse* of the statement is:

> The larger the range, the less likely that a submatrix will be similar.

So I would say that, if your aim is logical correctness, you should use the adverb *inversely.* This usage is also compatible with the common English meaning of the word *inversely*. The adverb *transversely* is just wrong here. From Merriam-Webster online dictionary:

**Transversely:** in a line or direction running from corner to corner.

But never use the adverb *contrapositively.* It doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for that @Peter Shor.  Like I noted in my reply to Hack Saw, I believe "inversely" is the more correct term to use but, just to be on the safe side, I have resorted to using "In Contrast..." as noted by Fraser.  I definitely WON'T be using the term "Contrapositively..." LOL.

Comment: I'm sure by strict logic the word is *inversely*, but in practice people (mathematicians and logicians aside) simply don't use this word when juxtaposing interrelated statements in this way.

Answer (score 4):

*Conversely* is correct. In this context, "conversely" does not have the same meaning it has in logic. It most strongly means a claim that reverses one or more aspects of a previous claim. It has a weaker meaning akin to "on the other hand".

My dictionary has this example, "We provide tech-support 24-hours a day, seven days a week; conversely, our competitors only provide tech-support 8-hours a day, five days a week." I personally wouldn't use "conversely" that way and reserve it for cases where the order or direction of something in a causal chain is reversed. But it is not incorrect.

There is nothing wrong with something like this: "Study more and you will get higher grades; conversely, if you study less your grades will surely suffer." The direction of the amount of studying and the movement of the grades are reversed. So "conversely" works perfectly. So long as there is some sense of opposition, it flows quite naturally.

Comment: I don't particularly object to *conversely*, though I find it odd that I'm okay with *correspondingly* as well, and superficially these words seem to be opposites. But I'm not keen on the *"on the other hand"* part, which implies that the second "rule" somehow *contradicts* the first. In fact, I feel it "almost" follows as a logical consequence.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use **and** - the problem with using words like **transversely** or **inversely** is that they may have very specific meanings in the topic of matrix maths which could cause confusion.

Even if they don't people might think they have a technical meaning and be trying to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most appropriate word is **correspondingly**.

Substituting **X** for *range is lower*, and **Y** for *submatrix is likely to be singular*, we have

If **X** is true then **Y** is true. Correspondingly, if **X** is not true then **Y** is not true.

Although the second statement doesn't logically *have* to follow from the first, this will often be the case for many non-trivial propositions of the form *"If X then Y"*. A shorter way of asserting both is *"If* **and only if** *X, then Y"*.

Although it seems odd, I also endorse @David Schwartz's **conversely**, despite the fact that superficially this word is the direct opposite of **correspondingly**.

If we can use an expression rather than a single word, I'd say **by the same token**, which I think implies a relationship between the two statements without getting bogged down in whether it's *inverse, converse,* or *corresponding*.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want "transversely" or "conversely" or anything else.  Those two sentences *mean exactly the same thing*!  If you really feel the need to repeat yourself, I suppose you could write "To put it another way..."